# How to prevent the Open/Save dialog when navigating with InternetExplorer.Application in powershell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, com, web-scraping

I am trying to download a file without seeing the open/save dialog of internet explorer. The login form is much more complex than sending a web request so I am limited to use InternetExplorer.Application.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter the username and password..."
$username = $credentials.UserName
$password = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.navigate("https://example.com/getFile?downloadId=123")

$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("fm1").submit()
```

On executing the above code, the login works perfect and the download is getting initiated but I am seeing a window like below which is what I want to supress. While I get that this setting can be changed by the end user, any suggestions to automatically download via powershell would be good.

[image: IE Download confirmation dialog]

*Above is an example window.*

Comment: It looks like there is no easy way to do this for modern IE versions (10/11). See this article and comments: [Internet Explorer: Disable "Do you want to open or save this file?" download prompt](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @beatcracker, via a registry setting, you can disable the prompt for a file type.

Inside the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` key (create it if needed), you will have to add an entry per file type.

First you have to get the *ProgID* for the file type you want to target.

You can use the assoc command to get it:

```
C:\Windows\System32>assoc .docx
.docx=Word.Document.12
```

In the registry you then have to create a new value named `Word.Document.12` with value `0`.

Of course, this would need to be deployed (GPO?) for each user of each workstation ... which is tedious.

Comment: I've tried this for the `exe` files (IE 10/ Server 2012, site added to`Local Intranet` zone), but no luck. I haven't tried `EditFlags` mentioned in article comments though.

Comment: I don't have any prompt on Internet websites for exe files ... I must have messed it up already ...

Comment: What's your IE/OS version? Can you post your registry key contents here?

Comment: No I mean it was already disabled in some way, my registry key only contained an entry for PDF files.

Comment: Oh, I see. Btw, I think it could be done without GPO, just write registry before launching IE and restore it back after closing IE object.

Answer (score 0):

I've fleshed out @sodawillow 's Answer in the form of a script below, as I will be running the web scraper script from different servers/accounts, but I couldn't get the prompt to go away. IE version is "Windows Server 2016". Hopefully others will have more luck. Please let me know if you do get it working with my script.

```
$path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\"
$item1 = "AttachmentExecute"
$item2 = "{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
$path1 = $path+$item1
$path2 = $path+$item1+"\"+$item2

if ($item1 -notin (Get-ChildItem $path | foreach-object {$_.name.split("\")[-1]})) 
{
    New-Item –Path $path –Name $item1
    New-Item –Path $path1 –Name $item2
    if ((Get-Item $path2).Property -notcontains "Excel.Sheet.12") 
    {
        New-ItemProperty -Path $path2 -Name "Excel.Sheet.12" -PropertyType "Binary"
    }
}
```